# Matlab: How to clear the previous output image

Tags: image, matlab

I define values for the variables and call the function, it returns the output image  in the figure. But when i want to test another set of data, the output image will come out, it's together with the previous output image. How can i solve it, do i need to add what code at the end of the function file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `close all` before your generate the new figure if you're not interested in the old output figure, or make a `figure` call before creating the new image to ensure it pops up in a new figure window. Or, you can overwrite the current open figure by setting `hold off` first, although that's specifically for graphs.

Comment: @Ivy - you ought to post your code so we can see what exactly is going on.